# How do I move C: drive to the top of the File Explorer "This PC"?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

File Explorer (Windows Explorer) --- I never use 3D Objects, Music, etc.  How do I move the C: drive to the top of "This PC"?

---

spikey_richie, Collapsing "This PC" would hide C: and D:.

Mr Ethernet, My Win10 screen does not provide the "Group by" option.

---

Keith Miller, I've updated the screenshot. I display "This PC", then I right click "This PC". What is a content pane?

---

Keith Miller, The key is to right click on an "empty space" in the content pane.  Then it displays the the group option.

Unfortunately, I use the Navigation Pane until I'm at the right folder.

---

The other comments clarify the complication.  It is unfortunate that Microsoft does not make this easy.  I wonder how many people select 3D Objects, Music, Pictures, etc. Hopefully a new rev will make this an option.

---

I decided to pin C: and D: to the Taskbar.

Comment: Why not just collapse Folders?

Comment: Your screenshot (just added?) is showing the Navigation Pane, whereas Mr. Ethernet's answer is for arranging the content pane, which  is how your fquestion originally read. Not sure if you can modify the sort order of those items in the Nav Pane.

Comment: The content pane is the right-hand pane that displays files & folders.

Answer (score 5):

**This can be achieved by changing the group order from Ascending to Descending:**

[image]

Comment: Don't worry about it. You tend to get fewer over time as you learn what sticks with this crowd. Out of interest, are you a Brit? I notice you spell things the same way as me! Like "behavio*u*r"

Comment: I saw your answer before it vanished. I suspect the reason behind the down votes was that you asserted as a fact that it's necessary to use a third-party application in order to reorder those groups of icons in Explorer. The problem is, that's not true and your answer contrasted with mine, which shows how to accomplish the same thing using options already available in Windows.

Comment: You said it *wasn't possible* to change it without using a third party app, which isn't true. You didn't say "I *prefer* it." You said "You can't change it. That's the way it is. If you want to change it in Windows 10, install an app..." (Paraphrasing it from memory.) It was a demonstrably false statement (that an app is required to change it), hence people apparently down voted it. Personally, I've just learned to live with it and I now prefer the C drive in the default location, but that's just me!

Comment: I don't see what you see.  I edited the initial post to show the image I see.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 1607 introduced a new registry key for defining which [Known Folders](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/known-folders) show up under the Navigation Panel and "This PC" screen.

For most users, you will have to create a new registry key at:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AllowedEnumeration
```

Then inside that registry key (folder) you can add a new `DWORD` value with the name:
`{0AC0837C-BBF8-452A-850D-79D08E667CA7}` and a value of `1`.

By default, everything will be hidden except for the Known Folders that you add to that registry folder.
If you want to make other folders visible again, consult the [Known Folder IDs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid) article from Microsoft. The Folder's GUID would be the registry key name and a value of `1` shows it, while `0` hides it.

You must restart your File Explorer to see the changes in the navigation panel.

Comment: "This PC" {0AC0837C-BBF8-452A-850D-79D08E667CA7}, "Downloads" {374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B} and "Documents" {FDD39AD0-238F-46AF-ADB4-6C85480369C7} for me. Finally. Only caveat: cannot pin folders from my profile anymore to "Quick Access" since those are in the "Profile" (now hidden) known folder :-/

Answer (score 2):

Notice the difference in context menu options when you right-click on **This PC** in the Navigation Pane(your screenshot) vs. right-clicking in the background of the content pane (Mr. Ethernets screenshot). It's the background of the Content Pane that offers the **Group By** and **Sort By** options.
Mr. Eternet's solution brings the **Devices and Drives** group to the top. If that's sufficient for your needs, go with that --- it's the easiet.
Romen's solution, creation of the **AllowedEnumeration** key, will hide the User folders under **This PC**, but also hides **Libraries**, **OneDrive**, etc. unless you add their GUIDs to the list of allowed folders:
[image]
You can be more selective by setting the T**hisPCPolicy** registry value to **Hide** for each folder under:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\<Folder GUID>\PropertyBag
```

[image]
Here are the folders found under **This PC**:

```
Name            HKLM\...\FolderDescriptions
----            ----                                  
Local Downloads {7d83ee9b-2244-4e70-b1f5-5393042af1e4}
3D Objects      {31C0DD25-9439-4F12-BF41-7FF4EDA38722}
My Music        {4BD8D571-6D19-48D3-BE97-422220080E43}
Local Pictures  {0ddd015d-b06c-45d5-8c4c-f59713854639}
Downloads       {374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}
My Pictures     {33E28130-4E1E-4676-835A-98395C3BC3BB}
Local Music     {a0c69a99-21c8-4671-8703-7934162fcf1d}
My Video        {18989B1D-99B5-455B-841C-AB7C74E4DDFC}
Personal        {FDD39AD0-238F-46AF-ADB4-6C85480369C7}
Desktop         {B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}
Local Documents {f42ee2d3-909f-4907-8871-4c22fc0bf756}
Local Videos    {35286a68-3c57-41a1-bbb1-0eae73d76c95}
```

This bit of **PowerShell** does it for you. This must be run from an ***Admin*** PowerShell  console window. IIRC, the **PropertyBag** subkey & value for **3D Objects** don't exist by  default, so this code will create them if they don't exist:

```
$FDPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions'
$RegEx = '3D|My |Local [^A]|Personal|^Downloads|^Desktop'
Get-ChildItem $FDPath |
Where-Object{ (gp $_.PSPath).Name -match $RegEx } |
   %{
       $PBPath = join-path $_.PSPath 'PropertyBag'
       If (!(Test-Path $PBPath)) {
          New-Item $PBPath | Out-Null
       }
       $splat = @{
           'Path'  = $PBPath
           'Name'  = 'ThisPCPolicy'
           'Value' = 'Hide'
       }
       Set-ItemProperty @Splat
   }
```